# Roots of $\prod_{j=1}^{m-1}(z+j)=m!$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, roots

Is there a simple argument (probably by using results from algebraic number theory) to show that the equation $\prod_{j=1}^{m-1}(z+j)=m!$ has no roots with $\Re(z)=1/2$ for all $m\geq 2$? Or is this incorrect?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The question should be written in such a way that it is possible to understand it even without reading the title.

Comment: Thanks! I modified it.